# JQuery Validate Mutli Select

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-validate

I have following HTML and I am using JQuery Validation plugin. I want it so that if user selects first option "Select" it should not allow to post form.But its not working anyone knows why ? Its working fine for Select Dropdown but not wit multiple="multiple".

```
<select multiple="multiple" size="2">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Can you post your relevant JavaScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The jQuery [.val() method returns an array containing each selected option](http://api.jquery.com/val/) when working with  elements. If no items are selected it'll return an empty array, and if the first item you listed is selected then the array will contain a single item that has a value of "".

You could try this  instead:

```
<select multiple="multiple" size="2"> 
  <option></option> 
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option> 
  <option value="saab">Saab</option> 
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option> 
  <option value="audi">Audi</option> 
</select>
```

However, since it's a multiple select, do you really need a blank item anyway?